# Noise on the PWM signal. What value of capacitor should i add to decrease the noise?

Tags: pwm, noise, inductor, motor-controller

I have noise on my 60Hz PWM output. The PWM output is going to the ESC to control the motor. Below is the signal with 5V per division. The PWM signal is a 60Hz, 10V signal. The duty cycle can be changed.

[image]

What I have noticed is that as i increase the duty cycle, the Brushless Motor suddenly increase and decreases; I believe noise on the PWM signal could be the issue. Below is the signal at 1V per division. What capacitor value should I add to decrease the noise?

[image]

Below is the signal when the motor suddenly increases or decrease. This time, it went from 4.1Amps to suddenly 8Amps. I hope someone can explain why this is happening. Some findings: when I increase or decrease the scale on the oscilloscope, it affect the motor. I don't understand why that is happening.

[image]

Comment: what are the characteristics of the noise (frequency etc)?

Comment: Hmm, I should look into that. Please hold on. I will post the signal soon. Thanks

Comment: I have added the photo of the signal with noise.

Comment: Doesn't look noisy at all. What's the practical problem?

Comment: At least at first glance, it seems unlikely that the noise level you're showing would have a significant effect on motor speed. Can you show traces of the signal when you see the sudden increase in motor speed?

Comment: The BLDC (brushless motor suddenly increases. Example: the motor suddenly goes from 4amp to 23Amp). I am outputting a PWM signal (60Hz, 10V) from a signal generator, and the PWM signal goes to the ESC (electronic speed controller). I don't know why the motor suddenly increases.

Comment: @SamShurp: Yes, can you show traces, like above, but when you increase the duty cycle, and the motor suddenly starts drawing 23 amps? The interesting question is whether you've done something wrong on the control side, and your duty cycle is suddenly increasing, or whether your power supply is causing a problem, and your noise level suddenly increases, or what exactly. For this, the 5V/division view will probably work nicely. Something is suddenly multiplying your current flow by >5x, so you probably won't have to look closely at details to see it.

Comment: Ok. I will quickly do the test and add the photo of the signal when the motor suddenly increases.

Comment: I just noticed something that I don't understand. As I increase or decrease the scale on the oscilloscope, the motor suddenly increases or decreases. Does this give us any clue on what's going on.

Comment: So I removed the oscilloscope from the system, and as I increase the duty cycle till 7percent, it worked well. After it reached 7 percent and more, the motor started to lag or decrease. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Since the signal that must pass is 60 Hz, you probably want to make sure everything up to around 600 Hz passes. So you can add a low-pass filter (RC) with 600 Hz cutoff frequency. And see if it helps. For example, 220 Ohms in series with 1uF. (That is around 720 Hz.)

Comment: Everything is behaving very erratically right now, so my suspicion is that there is something else going on that you have not caught yet. It would be good to remove variables from your setup and verify as many things as you can independently. For example, can you use a normal tester to validate that the ESC behaves as expected with the tester? Double check the signal from the tester, too, just for fun.

Comment: What are the specs of the ESC (input signal frequency range, input signal voltage range, pulse width range)? What happens when you send your PWM signal to a servo? Does it also misbehave?

Comment: https://hobbyking.com/en_us/turnigy-plush-32-40a-2-6s-speed-controller-w-bec.html?gclid=CjwKCAjwzIH7BRAbEiwAoDxxTtKXzLJzqRbISx9XJUiznTVuIYEH2IrgPWt0cE1qe0TdDVNgwlruCBoCTJ8QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds This is where I bought the ESC from. After doing some research, I believe noise is not the issue. I tried using multiple of the same ESC and it is behaving similarly (ESC suddenly increases). I have read the I may need to increase the timing angle of the ESC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an EE, but from my understanding, no. Twisted pair serves to render the pair "invisible" to electromagnetic interference since any voltage is introduced in both leads in exactly the same amount and phase, cancelling each other out.

An inductive choke, on the other hand, serves to filter AC signals at certain frequencies because those frequencies introduce alternating magnetic fields in the ferrite choke. The twisted pair would not induce a magnetic field in the choke, so you wouldn't filter the frequencies passing through the wire.

Now if you split the twisted pair and wound each leg around a separate choke, then continued with the twisted pair on the other side, you should be able to both get the noise resistance of twisted pair and the high frequency filtering of the choke. (You'd increase the noise in the wire by a small amount since part of the wire wouldn't be twisted pair. Again, I'm talking as a fairly well-informed amateur here, not an EE.)

Comment: This isn't quite correct. Twisted pair does help with reducing differential noise (since noise is theoretically induced in pair at the same time) but it will also help with reducing emissions, since the pair will remain tightly coupled along the whole length. A ferrite choke will also help reduce common mode noise, which again is important for both reducing introduced noise and also emitted noise. see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/275440/basic-rf-transission-in-noisy-environment/275448#275448

Comment: Thank you. I will add a choke and then twist the wire.

Comment: Adding a choke and twisting it solved the issue. Thank you